# OnCollisionEnter is called over and over again

Tags: collision-detection, unity

Currently I'm trying to let the player place a GameObject in the world. You can imagine this like a RTS game where you can place a building you have just build.
My problem now is, in order to avoid that the new GameObject intersects with another I check for collisions. For this my GameObjects have a BoxCollider (MeshCollider did not work) and a non kinematic RigidBody.
The first tests looked promising but now I'm facing a problem I can't quite explain: Sometimes, but not always OnCollisionEnter and OnCollisionExit are called over and over again, even when both objects are not moving. They overlap and stay that way. I had guessed that they always only get called once.
My Unity version is 5.3.0f4.

Further information: Each of my GameObjects have a guid so I can identify. They get generated when the GameOject is created.
The debug output in OnCollisionEnter and Exit look like this:

> OnCollisionEnter from 593b209f-cc63-4d31-9911-34c5f69ac224
>   Collided with: 77e05881-2adb-459d-a134-8205cf4e3327
>   OnCollisionEnter from 77e05881-2adb-459d-a134-8205cf4e3327!
>   Collided with: 593b209f-cc63-4d31-9911-34c5f69ac224
>   OnCollisionExit from 593b209f-cc63-4d31-9911-34c5f69ac224!
>   OnCollisionExit from 77e05881-2adb-459d-a134-8205cf4e3327!

And then the same output again.

I'm happy for any hints and help. :)

Comment: Can you explain further more about repetition and frequency of this happening?

Comment: Are you modifying its `transform.position` every frame? Because this causes the Rigidbody to basically "leave" its current position and "enter" anew. If so, try using [Rigidbody.MovePosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) instead, which is the cleaner way to move an object that has a Rigidbody.

Comment: @HamzaHasan: This happens about every second time I place the object. The loop also repeats when the game object gets destroyed. I have no reference anywhere anymore and call Destroy on the game object.

Comment: @Chris: No, the object's don't move. The only motion that might get applied (which I disabled for testing purposes but the problem kept happening) was RotateAround of the all the GameObjects within it's parent. No transform.position anywhere.

Comment: @Chris: I've checked the RotateAround again and not only set rotation to 0 but commented out the line entirely. Now the problem seems not to be happening anymore. This might be the cause, I will do some further checks.

Comment: Try using [Rigidbody.MoveRotation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html). Though if that doesn't give you the same functionality as Transform.RotateAround, use Transform.RotateAround on a hidden dummy GameObject, and then have your actual GameObject with the Rigidbody use Rigidbody.MovePosition and MoveRotation to match the dummy's position and rotation.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is a bug in 5.3.0f4. I've seen behavior like this repeatedly, even more suspect, namely that OnTriggerExit gets called when a collider is clearly in the middle of the object with the OnTriggerExit call.

Comment: @Chris: I've done some more testing yesterday and the problem did indeed happen when I completely disabled RotateAround. It just didn't happen that often. I'm calling RotateAround on an empty that serves as root element of my structure. It would be an ugly work around to split up all the rigid bodies and non-rigid bodies to rotate the entire structure. I can try your workaround later. Maybe it'll help. I'll get back with feedback as soon as I have it.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto: That would explain a lot. It is really strange behaviour and if it's a bug I hope it gets fixed soon. Do you know if there is a bug report already? If not I might open one.

Comment: Does your Rigidbody's property `Interpolate` set to `Extrapolate`?

Comment: @HamzaHasan: I've left it at the default, if I remember correctly it was Interpolate, but I have to check when I'm back home.

Comment: Do check one more thing that the colliders are not fit to pixel accuracy. Just insert your objects into the other colliders little bit.

Comment: @Skalli: I opened a ticket and it was accepted as a bug last night, although I don't see it on the list. Your issue is probably related, but might not be the same issue. It might be worth submitting a bug report of your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't get it to work with OnCollisionEnter I've switched to using OnTriggerEnter instead which works fine for now. It only has a problem when the model is rotated 180° but that is another question.
To work with triggers the following steps have to be done (most of it was done in the same way with OnCollisionEnter):

- Add RigidBody that has isKinematic set to true.
- Add Collider (MeshCollider works too) that is Convex and a Trigger